# Is it possible to check whether there is unsynced data that has yet to be synced to Firestorage?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, react-native

I'm building a react-native android application with Google Firestorage. A use case of the application might be the following:

A User adds data to the database while their device is offline. Sometime later the user connects his device to the internet and the offline data is automatically synced to Firestore. So far so good. But before he does that, I would like to display a text with something like "There is still unsynced Data. Please connect your device to the internet to sync it".

So my question would be: Is it possible to check whether there is still data in Firestores offline queue that has not yet been synced to the online database?

Something like

```
// Device is still offline
if (firestore.offlineQueue.length > 0) {
    alert('Hey, you´ve got unsynced data! Please connect your Device to the Internet.');
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried `var source = snapshot.metadata.fromCache ? "local cache" : "server";`?

Comment: thank you for your comment! I played around with it a little, but isn't it only firing at the moment firestore tries to write data to the database? I guess i could check for every query if `fromCache === true` and if it is, store something like `dataInOfflineQueue = true` and act accordingly. But is there also an event when the data in the offline queue gets synced so i know when to set `dataInOfflineQueue` back to false? Something like `addEventListener('offlineQueueSyncFinished', ...) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, I recommend you using the following line of code:

```
var source = snapshot.metadata.fromCache ? "local cache" : "server";
```

> Isn't it only firing at the moment Firestore tries to write data to the database?

No, it will only help you check whether you're receiving data from the server or the cache when reading, not when writing data. And yes, you can check whenever you query to see where the data comes from and act accordingly.

> But is there also an event when the data in the offline queue gets synced?

Yes it is. If you attach a complete lisner, which this is what it does. Please note, neither the success listener nor the failure listener will be called if your device cannot reach Firestore backend. The success/failure listeners will **only** be called once the data is committed to, or rejected by the Firebase servers.

Comment: Hi Maximilian! Have you tried my solution above, does it work?

Comment: hi alex, yep it pointed me in the right direction. thanks a lot!

Comment: for anyone interested, i used the [hasPendingWrites](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#events-local-changes) rather than `fromCache` parameter to check whether there are unwritten writes in the pipeline. it works really great!

Comment: @MaximilianSchmidt been looking for exactly this same where did you end up attaching your listener? did you find a way to subscribe to global firestore snapshots? then just check if one of the snapshots hasPendingWrites?

Comment: @ClayColeman i am connecting to my DB in the App.js on `componentDidMount` and then using `this.database.onSnapshot({includeMetadata: true}, response => {...})` in combination with react natives `NetInfo` module. Please see the code attached and feel free to ask if something is not clear: https://gist.github.com/maximilianschmidt/78d6303f58112bb5d7f1d9c156660748

Comment: @MaximilianSchmidt thanks for the quick response, that gist is perfect!! I already  set up a 'connectionChange' listener, so your solution was easy to add in as well.